# function to crop image create background color

Tags: php

i have this function, and when i pass a image which is smaller than the crop i want to create, it make bigger size image, thats all right, but the rest where there is no image, it fills with black color, do u know how to force it to create white, or specific color by using f.e. array(255,255,255) ??

here is picture it created for u to see directly what i mean.

[image: bed]

```
public function crop($x, $y, $width, $height)
{
    $copy=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    //$this->img = imagecolorallocate($this->img, 23, 123, 456);
    if (imagecopy($copy, $this->img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height)) {
        $this->img=$copy;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`imagefill`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) to set the colour of the image after you create it.

```
public function crop($x, $y, $width, $height)
{
    $copy=imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
    imagefill($copy, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($copy, 255, 255, 255));// fill with white
    //$this->img = imagecolorallocate($this->img, 23, 123, 456);
    if (imagecopy($copy, $this->img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $width, $height)) {
        $this->img=$copy;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```